# Docker - Access to Host from Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I access the host from the container? For example, I want to run a script on the host? are there any other ways to do this ? I thought only of SSH? are there other ways?

Comment: The whole point of running a program in Docker is that you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this on Ubuntu 20.04, but should be more or less the same on all UNIX boxes... you will need to either mount a local dir to your container or use volume. That way, a particular local dir where you have your local script will be mounted to the folder within your container

Start your container using `-v` option

```
docker run -d -v /home/rootuser/LocalMcScriptFolder:/app/ContainerFolder YOURIMAGE
```

Go into your container, go to the folder and run the script

```
docker exec -it CONTAINERID bash
$cd ContainerFolder
$pwd
/app/ContainerFolder
$./test.sh
```